How do you solve instantaneous 3 body collisions
A few years ago I built myself a very basic python program that did some very basic collision mechanics between particles with a mass and velocity and it was helpful in learning a few things and visualising.
This was done using momentum conservation laws and kinetic energy laws.
Constraints:
This system was inheritly restricted to an XY plane with no rotation or spin on the bodies.
A thing that's been bothering me for ages is how do 3 way collisions work.
I've seen answers where they basically apply the resultant of A and B, B and C, C and A etc and seem to do some cross product variation to conclude the result but I'm not convinced by this.
This doesn't intuitively feel like this is happening instantaneously across all 3. I feel like this is more akin to a linear solution or planar, but I can't understand why as that would mean that it's not deterministic which also doesn't make sense to me as we supposedly know all the variables, I mean I've literally programmed the state.
I apologise if I've gone somewhere in some very basic assumptions and this is a bit of a silly question, but I would appreciate a mathematical based answer to visualise it better, matrix wise.
Appreciate all answers, thank you

Not a full answer, but I suppose you could solve for the collision between A and B and the collision between A and C. Then you know the result on A. Then I guess just do the same thing for B and C. Not elegant, but I guess it works.

@controlgroup yeah I'm aware, but I'm not convinced by this. I feel like I should be able to solve them simultaneously, as they're all dependant on each other. Like, I can solve for when and where they will collide together simultaneously, why can't I go from there to see their resultant velocities?

If there is a way to just solve for all three bodies at the same time, I'm not aware of it. Stuff always gets more complicated when you add a third.

All things considered though it's highly improbable that three bodies actually collide at the exact same time in reality. No solution might exist because there isn't a physical circumstance that the solution would predict. Or maybe I'm completely off my rocker.

@controlgroup I'm aware, that's why it's a hypothetical question. Just curious as to how it works, I want it to make sense for me

@controlgroup The problem with that is that (most likely) the order of collisions matters.  ((A,B),C) is not the same as (A,(B,C)).

@FlatterMann this is why I'm not convinced, if they all collide simultaneously, this order seems to be a deciding factor

My point is that I don't find it likely for three bodies to collide at the exact same time. I can't imagine a physical scenario where that would happen in a way that it isn't actually just A to B and then B to C or A to B and then A to C.

@Max The simultaneous collision of two hard bodies is a corner case. In general for bodies with arbitrary shape it's not even a given that there will only be a single collision. Imagine a marble colliding with a bottle... it can enter the bottle and undergo numerous internal collisions before exiting again. The collision of three and more bodies can also cause non-trivial trajectories. This is not an easy problem.

@FlatterMann I completely understand how improbable it is, but that doesn't mean it can't occur. So when it does, how do we quantify what happens? It's a bit useless to tell me "but it's not probable to happen" when I'm beginning with hypotheticals to begin with.

@Max My point was exactly that the solutions may not be continuous. Coming from the direction of ((A,B),C) may not result in the same limit as (A,(B,C)) and depending on the shapes this may not even be a function with only two possible values (because very weird things can happen when hard bodies are bouncing off each other). In that case we would have to make an arbitrary choice.

@FlatterMann yes I completely agree, this is why I'm not convinced with those solutions, so why do we make them! You're not answering my question. How do we solve them? Why are they non deterministic if we have to make a choice?

@Max There is no promise in Newtonian mechanics that the evolution is continuous in the initial conditions. There are very simple examples to demonstrate that (e.g. a rolling ball falling off the edge of a table).

How did you solve it for 2 particles?
I ask because there's not actually enough information in the question to determine what happens in a collision.  Consider a simple example of two equal mass objects on a path directly towards one another at the same velocity?  What's the final result?  One answer could be that they bounce back off each other and both end up with the opposite velocity.  Another answer could be that they glance off each other and both change direction 90 degrees.  Both of these solutions are valid from a conservation of momentum and energy perspective.  Some additional information is needed to constrain the answer.  For example, one may make a choice to assume that all motion is within a particular plane.
In a real physics situation, the material properties and the surface shape of the objects will play an important part, along with the geometry of the collision itself.
In a 3 body collision, you simply need more constraints.  Real physics will often solve it with flexibility, such that a collision takes more than an instant.  But if you have a simulation which must resolve it in an instant, you will simply need to add more constraints.  Which constraints you add depends greatly on the materials.  It's entirely possible that for some collisions, you might have two large masses and one small mass and have the system eject the small mass with a very high velocity.  It all depends on details.

This is a fair comment, I do have constraints in my program, let me make edits. But basically there's no 3rd dimension and no spin/rotation

It would also be helpful to understand a little more of what you are trying to learn from this simulation.  Not all simulations are designed to simulate everything.  We typically need to tailor our simulations to the particular reason we are simulating in the first place.

A lot of people seem to be focused on the improbable/why part.

Is it not enough to say, I don't understand what happens when it does, and I want to know?

As a simulations engineer, the why is actually meaningful.  As I have been taught, "All simulations are wrong; some are useful."  Whether a simulation is useful or not depends on what one intends to do with the results.  If the intent is "I don't understand what happens when it does, and I want to know.," then the next question is "what is 'it?'" Describe the real life collision you seek to model.  We call this the "simuland."  Once we understand this, we can start looking into what models have sufficient fidelity to model the effects you care about.

Three tungsten (very hard) spheres colliding on a billiard table is very different from three elastic balls colliding, which is very different from a hydraulic press and a plate pressing against an object under test, which is very different from a 3-body gravitational system that might eject one of the bodies.   Note that all of those describe real-life simulands, not simulations or simulation scenarios.  None of them used the language of your simulation.

Depending on the collision you seek to model and what you intend to do with the information, the process of handling the collisions sequentially may be sufficient.  On the other extreme, the answer may be that you need to do computational fluid dynamics to sufficiently model what is happening in the real world.  It all depends on the simuland, and what you need to know about it from your simulation.

As a vague rule of thumb, without knowing the simuland, I would dare to say that if one is not modeling the non-conservative aspects of collisions (deformation), one probably is not modeling at a fidelity which can accurately capture a 3-body collision.  But I could be wrong.  The specific simuland you are interested in might be an exception, and your simulation could model it just fine.
